# Por que cuando quiero crear un archivo en html5 a través de visual studio code, el icono que me aparece es el "Dj" y no el de html?

Tags: html, css, django

Estoy consiente que he estado trabajando con Django algunas cosas pero de prueba únicamente pero al parecer al instalar Django y sus librerias no se si desconfiguro la extensión de html5.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguna de las herramientas instaladas de Django cambió el icono por defecto para html en Visual Studio Code, hay extensiones que asignan iconos por defecto a cada tipo de archivo, por ejemplo material icons, Nomo Dark Icon Theme.

En el caso de dejar de funcionar emmet despues de instalar extensión de django, se debe hacer lo siguiente:

Estando parado en cualquier archivo HTML, Presionar f1, buscar "json" y seleccionar el que dice "open settings(JSON)"

Una vez allí se debe agregar al JSON lo siguiente:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}
```

Es decir, si por ejemplo tienes lo siguiente:

```
{
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Al agregar la línea, debería quedar así:

```
{
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}
}
```

Guardar el archivo de configuración si es necesario, cerrarlo y volver a intentar utilizar emmet.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, sino más bien un comentario, por favor leer [answer]

Comment: Pero por ejemplo la función de emmet al momento de poner html5 para que te pueda poner los metas, scripts, etc ya no lo hace. Sabes que puedo hacer para poder reestablecer html5?

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta, ahí están los pasos a seguir para resolver, espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis lo intentare. Gracias por el apoyo, Saludos!

Comment: A las órdenes, espero puedas resolver, si funciona no olvides por favor marcar la respuesta como solución, dandole al Visto al costado de la respuesta, así sirve para otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema y a mi me ayuda a subir un poco la reputación.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionas la parte donde dice Djando HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de todas las opciones seleccionas la segunda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ya por ultimo seleccionas html y listo, por lo menos esa fue la solucion que a mi me sirvio